# FIDO Multi-device Authentication Sync Technical Specification

Tags: u2f, fido, webauthn

Where/what are the technical specifications to sync FIDO passkeys?

FIDO passkeys are a quite hot topic. There is a white paper from FIDO Alliance about it. Several websites provide abstract descriptions which leave a lot to be desired in terms of how the actual mechanisms work.

The technical inner workings are very unclear to me. And I cannot find any document dealing with implementing passkeys on a technical level among the vast amount of technical specifications that FIDO published.

Syncing keys across devices creates all sorts of security concerns for me, and I would like to know how they technically approached them.

Can someone point me to a technical description or specification of the syncing of FIDO passkeys, or provide a technical explanation of how this works? Did I overlook something?

Comment: I am not mixing up terms and I do understand the technology. Yes, even "passkey" is based on Webauthn/CTAP/FIDO2. Yes, it all boils down to having a ECC signing key, stored securely in your device. Traditionally, the FIDO approach was that this key should _never_ leave the device. With passkey, this signing key seems to be happily synched around through the cloud etc. And the question is HOW? There are all sorts of security related problems that arise, and so far the only answer of FIDO alliance seems to be "It just happens magically". So if and where are any kind of spec for _FIDO passkeys_?

Comment: Uh, Fido has a FAQ that describes how keys are synced across devices. I'm afraid that to answer your technical questions, all I will do is to link to articles from the FIDO site, which you say you've seen, which means I'm still unsure what you're unsure about.

Comment: So, I'm re-reading your question and your comments, and it appears that you still do not understand what you are asking, and you are using the wrong terms. And I'm also guessing that you've gained more understanding since you first wrote the question, which adds to the confusion. The answer *to what you asked* is here: https://media.fidoalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/How-FIDO-Addresses-a-Full-Range-of-Use-Cases-March24.pdf But first you need to get your terminology straight.

Comment: "Passkey" is not a technical term. You are looking for "multi-device credential". And that is just a sync function on top of webauth. The syncing function is not provided by FIDO, but by the devices (this is explained in the whitepaper I linked above). So, if you want to know how keys are synced technically, then you will need to narrow down what devices you are talking about and look there. But, again, this is all explained in the technical docs provided by FIDO, which you say you read. So, if these comments do not answer you, then you need to rewrite the question.

Comment: For instance: https://developers.google.com/identity/passkeys/supported-environments#:~:text=When%20the%20user%20creates%20a,with%20the%20same%20Google%20account. and https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphf538ea8d0/ios#:~:text=iPhone%20stores%20your%20passkeys%20in,%2C%20or%20tvOS%2016%20required).